# OpenID Connect account recovery when the user can't access the IdP?

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, account

I'm working on an app that uses public IdPs for identity only. I've been wondering if, for whatever reason, the IdP removes the user account or loses their user records, how does the user get their account back on my app? Is there a standard or protocol for this? I was thinking something like providing the user a recovery key/phrase that can be used to prove they are the account owner and allow transferring the account to a new IdP.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no standard to do this. Ideally, before you decide on including an IdP you probably should question "is this provider recommended for my app". If you don't trust the IdP you would be integrating with, I recommend not using them.

Sure you can provide workarounds like you suggest, but the best one may just be:
**Write down the users email address**. If the IdP is also the users email, then ask them for a backup email. Although all of that is likely an unnecessary extra amount of work, and likely if they lose access to their IdP login they have a lot more problems to worry about than using your app.